# How to Keep Netbeans 10 in Dock in MacOS X

Tags: netbeans, macos-mojave

I was wondering how I can Keep Netbeans 10 in Dock in MacOS X ( Mojave). After I open the Apache. I click on the icon and set it to "Keep in dock". but when I shut it down and come back to it after closing the NetBeans, it just loads java and does not run NetBeans.